# Making mouse disappear in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing some problems while running selenium automations.

1. I use moveTo function of Actions class in selenium to hover over a web element. Now, I want to take the mouse out of this element to some void place or make it disappear.
2. Another issue I am facing is mouse stays at the same place even if I reload the webpage.

I don't want to use moveTo(WebElement, offset_X, offset_Y). I tried searching for a way where I can move the mouse to particular coordinates without mentioning any WebElement but was not able to find anything like this.

Could anybody suggest me how to do the same?

Comment: Just a general advice: if you're moving the mouse in order to click an element, then your test might not work properly on different browsers (mobile browsers in particular). Use `findElement(...).click` instead if possible...

Comment: I am moving the mouse in order to see the hover over effect on element.

Answer (score 0):

Try Java Robot here..

```
WebElement targetElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Value"));
Point coordinates = targetElement.getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(), coordinates.getY() + 65); //replace 65 with your value to locate as you desire
```

Comment: How do I attach the current browser session with this Robot?

Comment: you dont need to add any library files; This is definitely going to work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can make the mouse disappear by moving it outside of screen, sample code as below:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Dimension SCREENSZIE = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
robot.mouseMove(-SCREENSZIE.width, -SCREENSZIE.height);
```